# How to generate Courier New U+2588 █ symbol by TCPDF?

Tags: php, unicode, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I need to generate the symbol U+2588 █ (Courier New) with TCPDF. I am currently using the `TCPDF::Rect` to get something similar.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this example](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_008.phps) on the TCPDF website, TCPDF supports Unicode. Therefore, you can just include your Unicode symbol (`U+2588 FULL BLOCK`), and specify the font as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

If the required font glyph do not exist, then you have to edit the font using FontForge and add it.
Then you can convert the TTF font directly using the addTTFfont() method (requires the latest TCPDF version).
Check the http://www.tcpdf.org website for further information and examples.